# Unable to find explicit activity class exception even if the class is declared in the projects manifest

Tags: android, android-library

I transformed my project into a library.  This project just displays a blank activity.  I imported this library into another project where I want to call it thru the projects main activity but I keep on getting the error below even if I already declared the activity inside the projects manifest.

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.package.name/com.package.name.BatibotActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This is my project manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="pak.paks.pocket" >
         <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.package.name.BatibotActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            </activity>

        </application>
</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

this is my BatibotActivity

```
package com.package.name;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

public class BatibotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_batibot);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**
This is the class that is calling the BatibotActivity

```
package pak.paks.pocket;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void submitBtn(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.name",
                "com.package.name.BatibotActivity"));

        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: is `BatibotActivity` extending `Activity`? Are you editing the correct `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Double check that `BatibotActivity` is actually in the correct package. Do you use ProGuard, if so, are you keeping all `Activity` classes, and not just `MainActivity`?

Comment: Post your BatibotActivity class

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the BatibotAcitivity its my only activity inside the .aar library

Comment: @Blackbelt I am editing the projects manifest file not the libraries manifest

Comment: I am just asking because I saw lot of users editing the manifest under `build/`

Comment: @blackbelt no worries :D sorry if my english is really poor its not my first language hope I always get into trouble in forums coz sometimes I sound rude or something

Comment: The problem is how are you starting the BatibotActivity. Please update the question with the code to open it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the solution was updated to fix your issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the log message, you are trying to open `com.package.name/com.package.name.BatibotActivity`, but the Activity registered on AndroidManifest.xml is `pak.paks.pocket/com.package.name.BatibotActivity`.

The first parameter for ComponentName is the package name. This is the correct code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("pak.paks.pocket", "com.package.name.BatibotActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I updated my question to show the main activity of the project that is calling the Activity inside the library.  @edit2

Comment: I edited my answer with the correct code to start the activity!

Comment: It works! But can you explain if I understood it correctly the first parameter for ComponentName(thePackageOfTheParentActivityOfYourProject, packageAndActivityFromLibrary)
is there a documentation that explains this?  Also why is it using the ActionBar of Pocket instead of the Batibots Action bar. when the batibot activity was called

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your manifest tag's package attr.

```
<manifest package="com.package.name">
<application>
...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the package part of the manifest